# UITableView inside UITableViewCell not giving correct result

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need to show following structure in UITableView. I created childTableView in MainTableViewCell. Also both tableviewCell needs to calculate dynamic height based on description.

```
    [
        {
            "schedule_type": "appointment",
            "schedule_id": “1234”,
            “schedule_desc”: “This is long text. Needs to mange with dynamic height in UILabel”,
            “activities” : [
                        {
                            “activity_id” : “12”,
                            “activity_desc” : “long description”
                        },
                        {
                            “activity_id” : “123”,
                            “activity_desc” : “long description”
                        },
                        {
                            “activity_id” : “121”,
                            “activity_desc” : “long description”
                        }
                    ]
        },
        {
            "schedule_type": "appointment",
            "schedule_id": “1234”,
            “schedule_desc”: “This is long text. Needs to mange with dynamic height in UILabel”,
            “activities” : [
                        {
                            “activity_id” : “12”,
                            “activity_desc” : “long description”
                        },
                        {
                            “activity_id” : “123”,
                            “activity_desc” : “long description”
                        },
                        {
                            “activity_id” : “121”,
                            “activity_desc” : “long description”
                        }
                    ]
        }

 ]
```

To calculate dynamic height what I did is, Inside MainTableViewCell I write following code.

```
self.childTable.dataSource = self;
self.childTable.delegate = self;
[self.childTable reloadData];
[self.childTable layoutIfNeeded];
self.childViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.childTable.contentSize.height
```

but When I put breakpoint to calculate childTableView height it gives me default value of cell i.e. 44. So, it is not updating as per content and my entire cell looks messy.

Is my approach correct or Is there any other better approach to achieve above data in tableview?

Answer (score 0):

If you put your set up code in view did load, it won't work. 
You need to add `self.childViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.childTable.contentSize.height` to override of `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. If your constraints are set up correctly, e.g., flexible, you will have the right value for `self.childTable.contentSize.height`.